# Typeahead with HTML Form - Auto Fill Next Cell Based on Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the Twitter bootstrap-typeahead plugin with an HTML form:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

which is working well. I would like the next cell in the row, which is a select menu, to be automatically selected to an option based on the user's selection in the previous cell. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/WNpy5/

If the user enters "New South Wales" for the State I would like the Country to be set to "Australia", but with the option of changing this using the select menu. Likewise if the user selects "California" I would like the Country to be set to "USA".

I can easily extend the array of values used for the typehead State field to include a corresponding country value (not sure of the format though) and not sure if this is possible and how to tie it all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a javascript array of objects for countries with their respective states:

```
var countries = [{ name: 'USA',
                   states: ['Alabama', 'Alaska']},
                 { name: 'Australia',
                   states: ['New South Wales', 'Queensland']}]; // You can add rest of the states here
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WNpy5/1/

In demo, it auto selects country when state is entered and the focus is moved away from textbox.

Answer (score 1):

The typeahead plugin by default only takes a list of strings.  I created an extension to  that accepts an array of JSON objects which I believe is the feature you're looking for.

Source is here: https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead

An example for your case would be:

```
var states = [{ state: 'NY', country: 'USA'}, 
              { state: 'Ontario', country: 'Canada'}, 
              { state: 'Petoria', country: 'Petoria'}];

$('#myTextBox').typeahead({
    source: states,
    display: 'state',
    val: 'country',
    itemSelected: function(item, val, text) {
        // val = name of the country
        // text = name of the provice
        $('#Country').val(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Terry I will check out your plugin extension - looks promising.